# How to prove MAE is convex?

Tags: statistics, convex-optimization, machine-learning, linear-regression

Consider I have error terms ei in Linear Regression setting. If I want to prove the Convexity of the function,  showing the Hessian of that function is 0 should prove the function is convex.

$$f(w_j)=\frac{\left|x_{ij}w_{j}-y_{i}\right|}{n}$$

$$f'(w_j)=\frac{x_{ij}\left(x_{ij}w_{j}-y_{i}\right)}{n\left|x_{ij}w_{j}-y_{i}\right|}$$

$$f''(w_j)=0$$

Since I arrived at 0 it proves the function is convex. Did I do it right?

Comment: What makes you think you could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not differentiable. Fixing a particular $i$ and let $\lambda \in [0,1]$, we can then use triangle inequality to conclude that

\begin{align}
f(\lambda w_{j,1} + (1-\lambda) w_{j,2}) &= \frac{|x_{i,j}(\lambda w_{j,1} + (1-\lambda) w_{j,2})-y_i|}{n} \\
&= \frac{|\lambda (x_{i,j}w_{j,1}-y_i) + (1-\lambda) (x_{i,j}w_{j,2}-y_i)|}{n} \\
&\le \frac{\lambda| (x_{i,j}w_{j,1}-y_i)| + (1-\lambda) |(x_{i,j}w_{j,2}-y_i)|}{n} \\
&= \frac{\lambda f(w_{j,1})+(1-\lambda) f(w_{j,2})}{n}
\end{align}

Also, note that sum of convex function is convex.